# How to save just part of URL in Cypress (without domain name)

Tags: testing, url, automation, path, cypress

I'm writing CY test and was trying to solve it by myself for couple of hours but unsuccessfully. Could you please help me here a bit :)

Each time I run the test I'm getting new URL, e.g.

> https://website.com/en/info/is/here/

And I need to save only

> /en/info/is/here/ (so without domain name)

I need to compare it later with another href.

Could you please advise me the way how to do it or at least the direction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: used approach from @TesterDick but thanks a lot for all answers, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [cy.location()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location#Examples) command gives you named parts, so from the example `pathname` is the part you need

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:8000/app/index.html?q=dan#/users/123/edit')

cy.location().should((loc) => {
  ..
  cy.wrap(loc.pathname).as('url1')    
  ...
})
```

If you have search or hash as well

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:8000/app/index.html?q=dan#/users/123/edit')

cy.location().should((loc) => {
  ..
  cy.wrap(loc.pathname + loc.search + loc.hash).as('url1')    
  ...
})
```

Comment: thank you! :) I used cy.location("pathname")

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.split()` on the URL string.

Where you save it depends on the location of it's use.

Inside one test:

```js
let pathname
cy.url().then((url) => url.split('/').slice(3)).as('pathname1')

...

cy.get('@pathname1').then(pathname1 => {
  expect(pathname1).to.eq(pathname2)
})
```

Between tests:

```js
let pathname1

it('gets first pathname', () => {
  cy.url().then((url) => pathname1 = url.split('/').slice(3))
})

it('uses first pathname', () => {
  expect(pathname1).to.eq(pathname2)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) interface to parse your string (also used by cy.location)

```js
const urlString = 'https://website.com/en/info/is/here/'
const url = new URL(urlString)
const pathname = url.pathname  // yields "/en/info/is/here/"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
let firstUrl = null;
let secondUrl = null;
cy.url().then(url => {
   firstUrl = url;
});

/* sometimes later */ 
cy.url().then(url => {
   secondUrl = url;
});

/* sometimes later */ 
expect(firstUrl).to.equal(secondUrl)
```

If you want to just compare some part of these URL I recommend you using a regex expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript `split` to do this:

```js
let partUrl
cy.url().then((url) => {
  partUrl = url.split('com')[1] //saves /en/info/is/here/
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.replace()` and the Cypress baseUrl value, and then store that value in a Cypress environment variable.

```js
cy.url().then((url) => {
  Cypress.env('someUrl', url.replace(Cypress.config('baseUrl'), '');
}).then(() => {
  cy.log(Cypress.env('someUrl'));
})
```